# Why can I not print text "$!"?

Tags: perl

In Perl 5.26.2, when I run this code:

```
use POSIX qw(setlocale);
use locale;
setlocale LANGUAGE, "en_US";

print "$!";
```

I got an error:

> No such file or directory

How can I print the two characters `$!`?

Comment: No repro with 5.30.2 on macOS. Please [edit] to provide more debugging details. How exactly are you running this code? Is the locale installed?

Comment: You should check the return value of `setlocale` as described in [perllocale](http://p3rl.org/perllocale).

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should indicate if you try to print an error variable `$!` or a string `$str = '$!'`.

Comment: Your `setlocale` is definitely not working. I wrote an answer about that but I can't post it now that the post is closed. If you need help debugging it, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$!` is [a predefined variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$!) in perl.  And string that is built with double quotes will be interpolated.

Your code prints the error message produced by `setlocale`. To print literal "$!", you can use single quotes like `print '$!';`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues here. And it's not clear which one you're misunderstanding.

`$!` is a variable. If you print a double-quoted string in Perl, it will expand any variables that are included in the string. If you don't want to treat `$!` as a variable, then you can either use a single-quoted string instead or escape the `$` to remove its special meaning.

```
print '$!';
print "\$!";
```

`$!` is one of Perl's special built-in variables. If you look it up in [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar), you'll see this:

> **$!**
>
> When referenced, `$!` retrieves the current value of the C `errno` integer variable. If `$!` is assigned a numerical value, that value is stored in `errno`. When referenced as a string, `$!` yields the system error string corresponding to `errno`.

So, when you print it, you are very likely to get what looks like an error - as it contains the last system error that your code generated. In this case, it's likely that your `setlocale` failed in some way and set the error variable.